# Loops in Matlab to solve a random walk problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, random-walk

The matlab exercise states  "Suppose now that you are playing the game with 100 coins (50 coins for each player to start) with a loaded dice such that the probability that the dice rolls to an even number is 0.53 instead of 0.5. (Recall you gain a coin on an even roll.) Write a for loop to create the transition matrix P and store this matrix as OneEmat" .

What is the loop supposed to to? How should I start the loop? How do I get a loop to create a matrix?

Any hints would be appreciated as I am quite loss on how to begin.

Comment: To make a transition matrix, loop over the rows (outer loop) and then over the columns  (inner loop).

Comment: what do you mean by loop over the rows?

Comment: for  i = 1:n  for j = 1:m  A(i,j) = blablabla end end